# Split string in pandas dataframe into individual columns - no delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` and one of the columns `df['x']` contains strings of length 100, each string of the form `'ABBABBBABBAABAABABBAAABAAAA...'`

How would I go about splitting this 1 column into 100 different columns, each containing only 1 character from the original string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.split`:

```
df['x'].str.split('',expand=True).iloc[:,1:-1]
```

or `str.extractall` with `unstack`:

```
df['x'].str.extractall('(.)')[0].unstack()
```